# Forest traversal in a BTree sort of structure

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, tree, traversal

I have a tree that consists of two types of nodes:

```
struct nodeStr_c
{
    std::wstring name;
    std::list<node_c*> children;

    nodeStr_c(std::wstring & vName);
    node_c* operator[] (int vPos);
};

struct node_c
{
    bool visited;
    std::list<nodeStr_c*> children;

    node_c();
    nodeStr_c* operator[] (std::wstring & vName);
};
```

You can imagine the tree looking like this:

[image: Tree image]

The leaf nodes are of type nodeStr_c, obviously. They can have any value, but I have assigned them mnemonic strings.

Looking at the above table, I need to get following information out of it:

```
CHEMISTRY | A:B:C       | A:B:E       | A:X:Y       | C
----------|-------------|-------------|-------------|---
value     | A(1):B(1):C | A(1):B(1):E | A(1):X(1):Y | c
value     | A(1):B(2):C | A(1):B(2):E |             | c
value     | A(1):B(3):C |             |             | c
value     | A(2):B(1):C |             | A(2):X(1):Y | c
value     | A(2):B(2):C |             |             | c
```

I have been working on this for last 1 week but still cannot figure out what algorithm to use. Could you guys please help me?

Comment: by what logic do you go from the tree structure to your (2d?) table?

Comment: can you post the code you were trying to execute in the past week and failed? we'll help you solve a problem but not do your job or assignment

Comment: It is not an assignment. I have been trying to parse this table for last 2 weeks but have run out of ideas. The problem is basically this: When at a node that has n children, I take kth path to proceed (k<n) then at that same level/depth in another node which has m children, I need to take kth path if k<m, else stop that thread. So, A(1):B(2):C should match with A(1):X(2):Y but not with A(2):... or A(1):X(1):...

Anyway, I solved this problem by throwing away the tree and creating hash tables from scratch along with some comparison operator overloads.